# Using the AND operating with an SQL COUNT() query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Is it possible to use the AND operator in an SQL COUNT() query? For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(field1) AS count FROM table WHERE field1='value1' AND field2=value2'
```

Right now I'm getting a syntax error with that query. Any advice?

Comment: You're missing a single quote at the beginning of value2 =)

Comment: that should be fine.. can you post the error?

Comment: I'm aware that I'm missing a quote, in the actual code I'm not missing one; that just happened when I copied it. The error is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'field2='value2'' at line 1"

Comment: Please post your *actual* code. Aside from the missing quote, the code you posted is correct.

Comment: This probably won't matter, but try putting $_COOKIE in curly braces, and quotes around your array key, `toUser='{$_COOKIE['user']}'`

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM table 
WHERE field1='value1' 
AND field2='value2'; -- btw, you were missing the leading quote from value2
```

Comment: I have the quote in my actual quote. It's only missing here.

Comment: @Max: If you know, then update the answer, so people will not lose time on it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get a syntax error because you've left out a quote mark before `value2`.

Comment: Sorry, that typo only happened when I copied it. In my actual code there is a quote mark there.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the word "Read", seems to be reserved.